# Get SSH server key fingerprint

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to *programmatically* obtain a SSH server key fingerprint *without authenticating* to it?

I'm trying `ssh -v user@host false 2>&1 | grep "Server host key"`, but this hangs waiting for a password if key based auth is not setup.

Comment: If you just want to get the local SSH key fingerprint: [`ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/key.pub`](https://superuser.com/a/453022/943615)

Comment: @MImamPratama, this is what I wrote in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631286/176127)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You could do this by combining `ssh-keyscan` and `ssh-keygen`:

```
$ file=$(mktemp)
$ ssh-keyscan host > $file 2> /dev/null
$ ssh-keygen -l -f $file
521 de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef:de:ad:be:ef host (ECDSA)
4096 8b:ad:f0:0d:8b:ad:f0:0d:8b:ad:f0:0d:8b:ad:f0:0d host (RSA)
$ rm $file
```

**Edit**: since OpenSSH 7.2 this oneliner works:

`ssh-keyscan host | ssh-keygen -lf -`

(credits to @mykhal)

Comment: Maybe `ssh-keygen -l -f - <(ssh-keyscan host)` does, though?

Comment: `-f` doesn't understand `-`, therefore `/dev/stdin`.  This said, both `foobar | quux` and `quux <(foobar)` are the same, as I understand it (except `<(…)` not being POSIXly correct).

Comment: @AndreasWiese they're different. `foobar | quux` redirect's quux's stdin. `quux <(foobar)` leaves quux's stdin alone but passes as its first argument the name of a pipe on the filesystem, which represents foobar's stdout. (To get a better idea of what's happening, try the same with `echo` instead of `quux`.) In this case it looks like `ssh-keygen` is too clever though, and it refuses to read the pipe. Not sure why.

Comment: OpenSSH >= 7.2 ssh-keyscan is able to read from stdin: `ssh-keyscan host | ssh-keygen -lf -`

Comment: Just do: `ssh-keygen -l -f <(ssh-keyscan host)`

Comment: That's a rather bad expression for shell scripts, as it depends on a shell supporting it, which POSIX shell doesn't.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -l -f -` does work much as expected in ssh-keygen 7.2 and above.  It produces some comment lines to STDERR that can be filtered out, as mentioned in the answer by Anthony Geoghegan or `ssh-keyscan host 2>/dev/null | ssh-keygen -l -f -`

Comment: Note that "host" here needs to be replaced with the actual name of your host. In my case "localhost" worked.

Comment: New versions of openssh (7.2 at least) will display the fingerprint as SHA256 (ex: `2048 SHA256:gYz11pP/v/SMzUD58jrZ+m1EFC1pvyMxvIrg4PYlvDY` ) If you want it in the old format, supply `-E md5` and you'll see something like `2048 MD5:0b:f5:49:d2:69:a5:49:2c:d9:45:75:87:4d:a0:7d:33`.

Comment: Didn't work for me got `/tmp/tmp.7vgPa3mi75 is not a public key file.`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers make sure you replaced "host" part with the name of your host. E.g. `ssh-keyscan 127.0.0.1 | ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin`

Answer (score 138):

I recently had to do this myself so I thought I’d add an answer which shows
how this can be done (with versions of *OpenSSH 7.2 or newer*) in one line
using process substitution:

```
ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan localhost 2>/dev/null)
```

(replace `localhost` with the hostname here)

---

The following text explains how these commands work and highlights some of the
differences in behaviour between older and newer versions of the OpenSSH
utilities.

### Fetch public host keys

The `ssh-keyscan` command was developed so that users can obtain public host
keys without needing to authenticate to the SSH server.  From its man page:

> `ssh-keyscan` is a utility for gathering the public ssh host keys of a
> number of hosts. It was designed to aid in building and verifying
> `ssh_known_hosts` files.

#### Key type

The type of key to be fetched is specified using the `-t` option.

- `rsa1` (obsolete SSH Protocol version 1)
- `rsa`
- `dsa`
- `ecdsa` (recent versions of OpenSSH)
- `ed25519` (recent versions of OpenSSH)

In modern OpenSSH releases, the *default* key types to be fetched are `rsa`
(since version 5.1), `ecdsa` (since version 6.0), and `ed25519` (since version
6.7).

With *older versions* of `ssh-keyscan` (before OpenSSH version 5.1), the
*default* key type was the out-dated `rsa1` (SSH Protocol 1) so the key types
would need to be explicitly specified:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa hostname
```

### Get fingerprint hashes of Base64 keys

`ssh-keyscan` prints the host key of the SSH server in *Base64-encoded*
format. To convert this to a fingerprint hash, the `ssh-keygen` utility can be
used with its `-l` option to print the fingerprint of the specified public
key.

If using Bash, Zsh (or the Korn shell), [process
substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) can be used
for a handy one-liner:

```
ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan hostname 2>/dev/null)
```

*Note*: With versions of OpenSSH before 7.2, the functions used by
`ssh-keygen` to read files, did not handle named pipes (FIFOs) very well so
this method wouldn’t work, thus requiring the use of temporary files.

#### Hashing algorithms

Recent versions of `ssh-keygen` print **SHA256** fingerprint hashes of the keys.
To get **MD5** hashes of the server key fingerprints (the old behaviour), the `-E`
option can be used to specify the hash algorithm:

```
ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf <(ssh-keyscan hostname 2>/dev/null)
```

#### Using a pipeline

If using a POSIX shell (such as `dash`) which doesn’t feature process substitution,
the other solutions using temporary files will work.  However, with newer versions
of OpenSSH (since 7.2), a simple pipeline can be used since `ssh-keygen` will
accept `-` as a filename for the standard input stream, allowing a one-line
pipeline command.

```
ssh-keyscan hostname 2>/dev/null | ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf -
```

Comment: Nice and thorough answer, this is certainly better than having a temporary file! May I suggest you provide a TL;DR in the beginning with the process substitution version, to make impatient folks find it faster? :)

Comment: Does not seem to work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; I get an error "/dev/fd/63 is not a public key file". The subprocess does work.

Comment: @melleb I found the same thing on an 12.04 system that I have access to. I suspect that `ssh-keygen` from older versions of OpenSSH have a problem reading from the FIFO / named pipe. I'll look into this (and update my answer) when I get some free time.

Comment: @melleb After spending my luch-time downloading various source code releases and inserting debugging `printf` statements in the `do_fingerprint()` function, I found that with versions of OpenSSH before 7.2, the functions used by `ssh-keygen` to read files, did not handle named pipes (FIFOs) very well so the process substitution method would not work.

Comment: This works, but if using it to verify a fingerprint, users should be aware that there's a race condition: the fingerprint you are checking with this command isn't necessarily that of the key you fetch, unless you dump the key before calling ssh-keygen on it.

Comment: You write 'this can be done (with versions of OpenSSH 7.2 or newer) in one line using process substitution' - but with OpenSSH >= 7.2 you can already pipe the ssh-keyscan output. Thus, perhaps you want to start with the pipe version and add the process substitution variant at the end. Or perhaps just leave it out as such old ssh versions perhaps aren't relevant anymore, in 2020.

Comment: Not sure about the comment of @CodeGnome, anything else hints at this answer to be the one that should be accepted. It removes the unneeded output and is a one-liner. I tested `ssh-keygen -lf <(ssh-keyscan 192.168.31.xy 2>/dev/null)` with a remote computer of my local network.

Answer (score 28):

`nmap` provides this ability by using the `ssh-hostkey` script.

To return the key's hexadecimal fingerprint:

```
$ nmap [SERVER] --script ssh-hostkey
```

To return  the key's content:

```
$ nmap [SERVER] --script ssh-hostkey --script-args ssh_hostkey=full
```

To return the key's visual bubble

```
$ nmap [SERVER] --script ssh-hostkey --script-args ssh_hostkey='visual bubble'
```

To return all of the above:

```
$ nmap [SERVER] --script ssh-hostkey --script-args ssh_hostkey=all
```

Source: [nmap docs](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-hostkey.html)

Comment: Do these examples assume that SSH is always running on port 22 ? What if ssh listens on a non-standard port ?

Comment: @MartinVegter (paraphrasing Guarin42, who couldn't comment:) nmap has the `-p` option which can specify a port, e.g. `-p 22000`. It's also possible to use the `-vv` option to increase the verbosity (amount of information given)

Comment: tried this out today - did not get any of the script promised/related outputs, only nmap progress and general info.

Comment: worked perfectly, it even found the different ports ssh was running on. Another useful arg is `ssh_hostkey=sha256` to show the current openssh standard fingerprint ;)

Answer (score 26):

The simple answer *when you already have access to the server* is:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

---

Now, you might not be using the RSA key: if when connecting, `ssh` tells you

> **ECDSA** key fingerprint is SHA256: XXXXX

You need to use `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` instead. (notice **_ecdsa_**).
A more universal command that lists all keys can thus be constructed ([source](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)):

```
for f in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub; do ssh-keygen -lf "$f"; done
```

You could write down the list when setting the server up, for future reference. Another option is to [store them in DNS records](https://simon.butcher.name/archives/2011/01/16/SSH-key-fingerprints-in-DNS) ([Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121163906/https://simon.butcher.name/archives/2011/01/16/SSH-key-fingerprints-in-DNS)):

1. Add the following DNS record: `<hostname> IN SSHFP <key-type> <hash-type> <fingerprint>` (`ssh-keygen` can print this line for you if you give it the *hostname*: `ssh-keygen -r hostname -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`)
2. Connect with `ssh -o VerifyHostKeyDNS=yes user@hostname` or enable it by default by adding `VerifyHostKeyDNS=yes` to the client config.

---

From the ssh-keygen (1) manpage:

> **`-l`**      Show fingerprint of specified public key file.  For RSA and DSA keys ssh-keygen tries to find the matching public key file and prints its fingerprint.  If combined with -v, a visual ASCII art representation of the key is supplied with the fingerprint.
>
> **`-f`** `filename`
> Specifies the filename of the key file.
>
> **`-r`** `hostname`
> Print the SSHFP fingerprint resource record named hostname for the specified public key file.
>
> **`-E`** `fingerprint_hash`
> Specifies the hash algorithm used when displaying key fingerprints.  Valid options are: “md5” and “sha256”.  The default is “sha256”.

You may want to use the last option `-E md5` when connecting from older ssh clients that default to printing the md5 key. Alternatively, from these clients, let ssh print the SHA256 with `ssh -o FingerprintHash=sha256 host`

Comment: This is the only answer that is of any use, the other answers just ask "what is the key of some-remote-host" which will print the key of the MITM if there is one… not a good way to verify a host key, it's like asking the person asking for your credit card "are you my banker?".

Comment: @SuzanneSoy Yes, you need to use (and trust) some other 'channel' to verify a key (or its fingerprint). I think this and other answers implicitly assume you're doing that, otherwise, as you point out, there's no point in generating/calculating a key's fingerprint at all.

Comment: Unlike some of the top answers, this answer actually works, and gives complete and usable info (e.g. the ECDSA key fingerprint that you actually see when doing the ssh connection)).

Comment: @SuzanneSoy Technically, you need some pre-trusted channel to the server to run this command as well, otherwise you don't know where the command is actually running. That could be something other than SSH, but any of the commands that take a hostname can be reliably run in that scenario as well by querying `localhost`. On the other hand, if you have multiple different users trying to access the server, the remote commands can be used to check if they _agree_ on the transmitted host key, which could be useful, without ever logging into the server.

Answer (score 9):

filezilla displays ***keys hashed with md5 in hexadecimal*** format.

to find this on your ***ubuntu linux*** machine use this command:

```
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f <(ssh-keyscan localhost 2>/dev/null)
```

note: replace "localhost" with the ip of the machine you wish to check.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18, but note, you will get difference results for `localhost` `127.0.0.1` or `domain.tld`. Check the fingerprint for the URL you are concerned with~!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shell script (mainly Bourne shell but using `local` keyword, which is available in most modern `/bin/sh`) I've written to do this. Use it like `ssh-hostkey hostname`. It will show both the sha256 and md5 format fingerprints for all hostkeys for the given hostname or IP address. You can also manually specify "`md5`" or "`sha256`" as the second argument to only show that particular format.

It uses a temporary file instead of piping to make it compatible with older OpenSSH packages (as described in other answers). The temporary file uses `/dev/shm` (shared memory) if available.

```
#!/bin/sh
usage () {
  printf '%s\n' "Usage: ssh-hostkey HOSTNAME [FPRINTHASH]"
}

ssh_hostkey () {
  local host="$1"
  local fprinthash="$2"
  local tmp=

  case "$host" in
    -h|--help|'')
      usage >&2
      return 1
      ;;
  esac

  case "$fprinthash" in
    md5|sha256|'') true;;
    *)
      usage >&2
      printf '%s\n' "Fingerprint hash may be 'md5' or 'sha256'" >&2
      return 2
      ;;
  esac

  if test -d /dev/shm
  then tmp="$(mktemp -d -p /dev/shm)"
  else tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
  fi

  trap 'trap - INT TERM EXIT; rm -rf "$tmp"' INT TERM EXIT
  ssh-keyscan "$host" > "$tmp/f" 2> /dev/null
  case "$fprinthash" in
    sha256|'') ssh-keygen -l -f "$tmp/f" 2> /dev/null;;
  esac
  case "$fprinthash" in
    md5|'') ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f "$tmp/f" 2> /dev/null;;
  esac

  trap - INT TERM EXIT
  rm -rf "$tmp" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

ssh_hostkey "$@"
```

Comment: This is a nice demo of wrapping lower level tools with command line options.  Includes a bonus of how to use shared memory `/dev/shm` which I never knew was so convenient to do.  Thanks for **sharing**!

Answer (score 4):

For my own server I use this:

```
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f <(cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub)
ssh-keygen -l -E sha256 -f <(cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I received `is not a public key file` with the accepted answer, I used this instead:

```
timeout 1 ssh -q -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/sshkey.tmp <hostname>; cat /tmp/sshkey.tmp && rm /tmp/sshkey.tmp
```