# Verify host key fingerprint in old format

Tags: ssh, openssh, fingerprint

OpenSSH's display format for host key fingerprints has changed recently - between versions 6.7 and 6.8.  When connecting to a new host, the message now looks like this:

```
user@desktop:~$ ssh 10.33.1.114
The authenticity of host '10.33.1.114 (10.33.1.114)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:9ZTSzJsnk0byQRs24iKoYrf/d5eDvQL60tR/zO41k/I.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

On the remote host `server` (which I reached through a 3rd machine, where I had accepted the key earlier using an older client), I can see the fingerprint with

```
user@server:~$ ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
256 a2:7e:2b:87:4c:47:69:16:78:9e:1a:4b:db:a7:a2:57  root@server (ECDSA)
```

But there's no way to match these two up.

If I install an older `ssh` version on `desktop`, and first connect using that, I see

```
user@desktop:~$ ssh 10.33.1.114
The authenticity of host '10.33.1.114 (10.33.1.114)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is a2:7e:2b:87:4c:47:69:16:78:9e:1a:4b:db:a7:a2:57.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

That matches, so I can safely accept it, and it gets added to my `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.  Then the newer version of `ssh` also accepts it.  But that requires me to build/install the older `ssh` version on `desktop`.

From [an answer to another question about server fingerprints](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268692/90751), I learned that the old form can be shown with `ssh-keygen -E md5`, and the new one is `-E sha256`.  But the `-E` option only appeared when SHA256 became the default - the version of `ssh-keygen` on `server` can only show MD5. To see the SHA256 fingerprint of the key I trust, I'd first have to retrieve it (eg. through that 3rd machine) and put it where the newer `ssh-keygen` can find it.  Or I'd have to run a newer `ssh-keygen` on `server`.  (`-E` means something completely different for `ssh`.)

How can I display both keys (the one that I trust, and the one that I'm being presented with) in the same format? Preferably without installing additional versions, or copying key files around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5 10.33.1.114
```

to get the old-`md5` fingerprint from the client.

Comment: And for `ssh-keygen` it seems to be `-E md5`: `ssh-keygen -E md5 -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

Comment: `command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: fingerprinthash`