# Unable to login to SSH remotely

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

When on the server i can login to localhost using:

```
ssh localhost    
username@localhost's password:  
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-40-generic x86_64)
```

However when I try and login remotely i get this:

```
ssh 1.2.3.4 -l username
username@1.2.3.4's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

The password is absolutely correct.

Edit: I added the verbosity to the client login and this is the output after entering the password

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: (a) is "username" actually "root"? (b) are you using the correct IP address?

Comment: Did you check the logs of `sshd`?

Comment: Use [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268692/108618) to fetch public host keys from the server in the two cases. If the responses don't match (note: the order of lines doesn't matter) then it's not the same server (*maybe* remotely you're connecting to the ISP's server?).

Comment: Use `ssh -v ...` to get more information.

Comment: @roaima No its not root

Comment: @waltinator I updated the question with the output from -vvv after entering the password. Doesnt help much.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It is the correct server.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the server OS or Distribution. If it has `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure` please add the lines tagged with ssh to your question. If it doesn't have this file please check other recently modified files in `/var/log` for entries tagged with ssh

Comment: FYI- you might want to obfuscate your IP address since it's public.

Comment: Any information from the server logs? Those will explain the reason, whereas client logs will only show a simple refusal

Comment: Have you edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` at all?