# How does "-" work in the "ssh-keygen -lf -" command?

Tags: ssh, openssh, options, fingerprint

I read this question

- [Get SSH server key fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126908/get-ssh-server-key-fingerprint)

In the answer and solution appears the following command (adapted here for presentation purposes)

```
ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X | ssh-keygen -lf -
```

I know that the first command isolated shows the `public keys` of the host. When the complete command is executed - thus the two parts - according with the final output, the public keys of the first command are used to generate the *fingerprint* of themselves.

**question**

- How does `-` work in the `ssh-keygen -lf -` command?

It is mandatory. I know `l` is to show the *fingerprint* and `f` to define a filename, but how is interpreted `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ssh-keygen -l` will ask you interactively for what public key file to show the fingerprint of.  With `-f` you give it the pathname of some existing file instead.

If the pathname is `-` (a dash), input is read from standard input instead of from a file.

This is a common practice that quite a few other commands also follow, most notably `cat` (`cat -` reads from standard input).

In your pipeline, the data on standard input is provided by the `ssh-keyscan` command.  The `ssh-keyscan` command will extract the public key of the mentioned host and pass it on to `ssh-keygen -l`. The `ssh-keygen` utility will output the fingerprint.

*Without* `-f -`, the `ssh-keygen` utility would try to use the output of `ssh-keyscan` as the filename to read the key from.

This is arguably bad design, as it's easy to programmatically determine whether the input to a program comes from a terminal or something that is not a terminal (like another command or a file). So in a sense, `-f -` *could* be made unnecessary.